# How to stop swiping the row in RecyclerView after reaching behind button width?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe

[image]

As the gif above, I swipe to the maximum distance and I going to release my finger.

What I want to see is that the black layout on the screen remains still and the red delete button can still be displayed.

However after I release my finger, the black layout become wider and covere the red button.

Here are some of my code:

row_content.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/whiteLayout"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:outlineProvider="none"
    android:translationZ="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:background="#FE3B30"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="22dp"
    android:paddingRight="22dp"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

SwipeHelper.java

```
public class SwipeHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
public SwipeHelper(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs) {
    super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(
        @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView,
        @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
        @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(
        @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
        int direction) {

}

@Override
public float getSwipeEscapeVelocity(float defaultValue) {
    return Float.MAX_VALUE;
}

@Override
public float getSwipeThreshold(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public void onChildDraw(
        @NonNull Canvas c,
        @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView,
        @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
        float dX,
        float dY,
        int actionState,
        boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

    if (dX >= 0) {
        super.onChildDraw(
                c,
                recyclerView,
                viewHolder,
                dX,
                dY,
                actionState,
                isCurrentlyActive);
        return;
    }

    MainActivity.ContentViewHolder contentViewHolder =
            (MainActivity.ContentViewHolder) viewHolder;
    LinearLayout whiteLayout = contentViewHolder.getWhiteLayout();
    TextView deleteButton = contentViewHolder.getDeleteButton();

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
            (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) whiteLayout.getLayoutParams();

    if (-dX >= deleteButton.getWidth()) {
        layoutParams.setMargins(
                layoutParams.leftMargin,
                layoutParams.topMargin,
                deleteButton.getWidth(),
                layoutParams.bottomMargin);

        whiteLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    } else {
        layoutParams.setMargins(
                layoutParams.leftMargin,
                layoutParams.topMargin,
                (int) -dX,
                layoutParams.bottomMargin);

        whiteLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

}


}
```

Could you tell me how to do? Thanks!

Comment: does anybody know it? Appreciate